# Sierpinski Carpet in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Saw this problem [here](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.demoen/PrologProgrammingContests/probs2007.pdf) and since I am a prolog newbie, I tried formulating a solution unsuccesfully. Here's what I have managed to make of this so far:

```
rewrite('X', [['X','X','X'],['X',' ','X'],['X','X','X']]).
rewrite(' ', [[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]).

rec(1, [], CurrentList, [CurrentList]).
rec(_, [], CurrentList, CurrentList).
rec(0, L, CurrentList, Result):- append(CurrentList, [L], Result).

rec(N, [H|T], CurrentList, Result):-
    atom(H),
    N > 0,
    rewrite(H, L),
    K is N - 1,
    rec(K, L, CurrentList, Temp),
    rec(N, T, Temp, Result).

rec(N, [H|T], CurrentList, Result):-
    N > 0,
    rec(N, H, CurrentList, Temp),
    rec(N, T, Temp, Result).

carpet(N):-
    N > 0,
    rewrite(Item, _),!,
    rec(N, [[Item]], [], Result),
    write(Result).
```

Essentially, I try to expand my first element and then expand each element created by the previous expansion.

Then I wrote the first rec fact that basically is there to place all expanded elements of the previous to last expansion in a list and signal where the newline will be placed but places parentheses from the start to the end of the next expanded group rather than from the start of the next expanded group to it's end.

I might have a lot of faulty logic so any other way to solve this problem would be welcome.

Comment: Oh, I just use it to get the first character for the first expansion (it gets the character that appears in the first instance of rewrite/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing yourself a favor by using `rec` as a predicate name. What is it supposed to do?

Here is my approach. It is based on simplifying the problem first, to only considering one level of rewriting of *one non-empty row* of symbols. Considering several rows is then simple by iterating that.

```
% expand_row(Row, Expansion): Row is a list of symbols representing one row
% of the Sierpinski carpet. Expansion is a list of rows, i.e., a list of
% lists of symbols, resulting from rewriting each symbol in Row.
expand_row([C], Expansion) :-
    rewrite(C, Expansion).
expand_row([C,D|Cs], Expansion) :-
    rewrite(C, ExpansionC),
    expand_row([D|Cs], ExpansionRest),
    maplist(append, ExpansionC, ExpansionRest, Expansion).

carpet_(1, [['X']]).
carpet_(N, Carpet) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    carpet_(N1, Carpet1),
    maplist(expand_row, Carpet1, CarpetExpanded),
    % remove one level of nesting
    append(CarpetExpanded, Carpet).
```

Note that this only computes the carpet, it doesn't print it. That's better done separately:

```
write_row(Row) :-
    maplist(write, Row),
    nl.

write_carpet(Carpet) :-
    maplist(write_row, Carpet).

carpet(N) :-
    carpet_(N, Carpet),
    write_carpet(Carpet).
```

Test:

```
?- between(1, 4, N), carpet(N).
X
N = 1 ;
XXX
X X
XXX
N = 2 ;
XXXXXXXXX
X XX XX X
XXXXXXXXX
XXX   XXX
X X   X X
XXX   XXX
XXXXXXXXX
X XX XX X
XXXXXXXXX
N = 3 ;
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX
X X   X XX X   X XX X   X X
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX
X XX XX X         X XX XX X
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX
XXX   XXX         XXX   XXX
X X   X X         X X   X X
XXX   XXX         XXX   XXX
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX
X XX XX X         X XX XX X
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX
X X   X XX X   X XX X   X X
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
N = 4 ;
false.
```